# select2 auto clear after submit (Laravel , Livewire)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have barcode scanner i want whenever submit barcode auto select and after than automatically clear the search box

````
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single1').select2();
        $('.js-example-basic-single1').select2('open');
        $('.js-example-basic-single1').on('change', function (e) {
            @this.set('item_id', e.target.value);
            $(this).select2('positionDropdown', true);
            $(this).select2("val", "");    
        });
    });
});
</script>
 <select autofocus class="form-control js-example-basic-single1" id="js-example-basic-single1" data-allow-clear="true" wire:submit.prevent="item_id" id="item_id">
<option  value="{{$item_detail->id}}-1">{{$item_detail->item->id}}-{{$item_detail->item->title}}-{{$item_detail->item->barcode}}</option>
</select>```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With select2, you need to clear it and then trigger the change.  This can be done using the library within your function above like so:

```
$(this).val(null).trigger('change');
```

That excellent library has [pretty decent docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items), including for the above question

Comment: i think there is a problem with livewire laravel , so the solutions are not working